# Live Wallpaper destroying wrong engine - "set wallpaper"

Tags: android, live-wallpaper

Edit: I am starting over / simplifying this thread...

Has anyone come accross this before.?

Using the Cube Enging as a test template, very basic.

I am in the preview screen of my live wallpaper and clicking/pushing "set wallpaper".

```
01-03 12:15:12.574: I/CubeEngine(6525): CubeEngine > CubeEngine  : 1
01-03 12:15:21.347: I/CubeEngine(6525): CubeEngine > CubeEngine  : 2
01-03 12:15:22.566: I/CubeEngine(6525): CubeEngine > onSurfaceDestroyed  : 1
01-03 12:15:22.566: I/CubeEngine(6525): CubeEngine > onDestroy  : 1
01-03 12:15:35.879: I/CubeEngine(6525): CubeEngine > CubeEngine  : 3
01-03 12:15:39.644: I/CubeEngine(6525): CubeEngine > onSurfaceDestroyed  : 3
01-03 12:15:39.644: I/CubeEngine(6525): CubeEngine > onDestroy  : 3
```

The numbers are the "engineID" of each wallpaper.

Here is a link to the zipped [source files](http://www.chamberlandhosting.com/app/android/000-CubeTest.zip).

Let me know if you get the same results.

1) Initial Live Wallpaper (000-CubeTest) preview > image 01

2) "Set Wallaper" > image 02

3) Back to wallpaper preview > image 03

4) "Set Wallpaper" > image 02

5) Back to wallpaper preview > image 04

6) "Set Wallpaper" > image 02

See the pattern... why is this happening?

Comment: Ok, I figured it out... Apperently you have to add/update a Wallpaper Preference in order for the current preview wallpaper to be recogized as new and valid. Otherwise it will remove the current preview. Hope this helps anyone else who ran into this.

Comment: Jon, sometimes I face issues like this. What kind of Wallpaper Preference do you refer?